# Нарезка строки регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Здравствуйте.

Есть такая строка:

```
{\"status\":\"ok\", \"id\":\"9582884\", \"type\":\"101\", \"url_id\":\"8791147\", \"url\":\"wall-63501025_305\", \"google\":\"\", \"bonus\":\"1\", \"res\":\"\", \"res_int\":\"0\",  \"token\":\"\"}
```

Её бы нарезать и получить массив всего внутри \".Как только я не пробовал,у меня не вышло.
До этого паттерны использовал только в AutoIt,они там,как мне кажется,реализованы божественно.

Так бы я нарезал эту строку в автоите:

```
#include <Array.au3>
$s='{\"status\":\"ok\", \"id\":\"9582884\", \"type\":\"101\", \"url_id\":\"8791147\", \"url\":\"wall-63501025_305\", \"google\":\"\", \"bonus\":\"1\", \"res\":\"\", \"res_int\":\"0\",  \"token\":\"\"}'
$a=StringRegExp($s,'([a-z0-9-_]{1,})',3)
_ArrayDisplay($a)
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: Откуда вообще пошла в массы идея о том, что всё что угодно можно распарсить регулярками? Рекурсивные грамматики (к числу которых принадлежит и JSON, и HTML) регулярками распарсить невозможно[.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994)

Comment: У вас что-то с джавой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведенная строка называется [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Если я правильно нагуглил то вам следует пользовать Json_Decode